# Ansible and hardware checks

Tags: ansible

I have to check different hardware and configurations elements on Linux machines using ansible, and I am not sure at all about how to do it (RAM, disk space, DNS, CPU...), I've understood that I can find nearly all I want in the ansible facts, but I do not understand how I can use it.

For example, I have to check if the RAM amount is at least of 4GB and have an alarm if not, so I tried many things, and... nothing works.

Here is an example of what I tried.

```
 - hosts: client
   remote_user: user

  tasks:
      - debug: var=ansible_memory_mb
      - debug: msg="total RAM is {{ ansible_memory_mb.real.total }}"
      - fail: msg="not enough RAM"t
      - when: {{ ansible_memory_mb.real.total }} < 4096
```

Could you tell me how it works ? and maybe there is a better way to do what I want using Ansible ?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the snippet you posted.

- Your indentation is off.  `tasks` needs to be at the same indentation level as `hosts`.
- The `when` condition needs to be part of the `fail` task block, not a separate list item.
- In general, you do not need to use `{{ ... }}` in a `when` condition, the entire expression will be treated as a Jinja template.

Try this:

```
- hosts: client
  remote_user: user
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_memory_mb
    - debug: msg="total RAM is {{ ansible_memory_mb.real.total }}"
    - fail: msg="not enough RAM"
      when: ansible_memory_mb.real.total < 4096
```

You can also use the [`assert` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) to check a condition or list of conditions.

```
- assert:
    that:
      - ansible_memory_mb.real.total >= 4096
      - some other condition
      - ...
```

Comment: So it is how it works ! (and yes, your code works)
Sorry for the indentation, it's only a failed copy/paste. I tried assert module, it's a seductive way to do what I want but fail/when look more adapted in what I want.

For the moment I will continue my tests for all the things I want to check, but I thing I begin to understand how Ansible works. Thank you !