# Ansible - How to check the physical memory and free disk is greater than some value?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

How to write an ansible task to check if the physical memory >=128 MB and free disk is >= 256 MB. i tried to get the output but i am not sure how to proceed further.

```
# Check the physical disk memory 128 MB and free disk 256 MB
 - name: check the physical memory
   command: vmstat -s
   register: phy_mem
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you start a playbook, Ansible first task is always

```
TASK [Gathering Facts]
```

This tasks fetch some internal variables used by Ansible but usable inside your playbook.

For example for a memory check look at variable ansible_memory_mb.real.total

```
- assert:
    that:
        - ansible_memtotal_mb >= 128
```

Now you want a list of all the internal variables :

```
ansible -m setup hostname
```

Here is the complete list [Ansible and hardware checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033996/ansible-and-hardware-checks) (names and stuff may changed between old and new Ansible release)

Version 2.3 Source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/setup_module.html
Current Source : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html

Comment: This answers just half of the question. But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26981907/402322) may answer the other part.

Comment: @Swat - Please open a new question and post in your Ansible YAML code that is showing this error.  I suspect you might need to add a "gather_facts: True" line to the YAML, or possibly change your test to "- ansible_memfree_mb|int >= 256" (note the inclusion of the "|int" cast).